# Dynamic nesting of v-for loops in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

Not sure if this is possible, but worth a shot.

I'm trying to build a system where a set of components could be dynamically rendered, in the same component, in a dynamiclly nested set of v-for loops.

To give an example.

let's say I have a series of `<div/>`s and a json in this structure

```
list : [
    ['Test','Test],
    ['Test2', 'Test2],
    ['Test3','Test3],
]
```

This would render:

```
<div>
   <div> 
     <div>
       Test
     </div>
     <div>
       Test
     </div>
   </div>
   <div> 
     <div>
       Test2
     </div>
     <div>
       Test2
     </div>
   </div>
   <div> 
     <div>
       Test3
     </div>
     <div>
       Test3
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

However, if I added another set of nesting,
e.g.

```
list : [
    ['Test','Test],
    ['Test2', 'Test2],
    ['Test3',['Test4', 'Test4']],
]
```

It would render like this,

```
<div>
   <div> 
     <div>
       Test
     </div>
     <div>
       Test
     </div>
   </div>
   <div> 
     <div>
       Test2
     </div>
     <div>
       Test2
     </div>
   </div>
   <div> 
     <div>
       Test3
     </div>
     <div>
       <div>
         Test4
       </div>
       <div>
         Test4
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

I know how this could be acomplished with a fixed level of nesting
e.g.

```
<div>
  <div v-for="(item,index) in list" :key="index">
    <div v-for="(subItem, subIndex) in item :key="subIndex">
      {{subItem}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I am unsure on how I could make it react to a dynamic level of nesting if it had to be interpreted at runtime.
If anyone has any ideas on this I would appreciate the help.

Edit: to clarify, the solution I would be looking for would work for a unkown amoint of nesting.

Comment: Do another round of looping and use v-if to determine whether or not to render (i.e. whether another nest exists).

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work if the it was nested further e.g [,Test, [Test, [Test, [...etc]] ]  ] @Arc

Comment: It should work fine.

Comment: You should use recursive functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two components `<list>` and `<list-item>` and in `<list-item>` call `<list>` recursively if item props is an array else render a normal `<div>` tag.

Like this:

```js
Vue.component('list', {
    props:["items"],
    functional: true,
    render: function(createElement,{ props, children }){ 
        return props.items.map((item)=>createElement('list-item',{ props: {item} }))
    }
});

Vue.component('list-item', {
    props:["item"],
    template: '<div v-if="isArray(item)"><list v-bind:items="item"> </list> </div>'+
              '<div v-else> {{item}} </div>',
    methods:{
        isArray:function(item){
            return Array.isArray(item);
        }
    }
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
    items:[
        ['Test','Test'],
        ['Test2', 'Test2'],
        ['Test3',['Test4', 'Test4']],
    ],
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>
   <list v-bind:items="items"></list>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this..you may try out the use of components and callback with own components for nested looping.
Is just an idea I not sure its work or not.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at, and it was my first thought (and probably what I'll do if I can't find any other way), but ideally I would do this all in the same component so that passing data would be eaier and I could avoid a complex vuex interaction